# Monitoring a log file while used by a daemon

Tags: linux, file, monitoring

i use mosquitto as a mqtt broker and forward all debug output to a log file.
With this [script](https://bitbucket.org/denilsonsa/small_scripts/src/327d437996a35e8447b2a60e6c647f244b16e3d9/sleep_until_modified.sh?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) called sleep_until_modified.sh i want to monitor the log file and start a script every time the log file changes.
 I start the script with: 
`while ./sleep_until_modified.sh mosquitto.log ; do ./scriptFile ; done`
The problem is that this process realising the changes of the log file only after quitting the mosquitto process.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inotify`.

Start reading here:  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/inotifywait.1.html

> `inotifywait` efficiently waits for changes to files using Linux's
>   `inotify(7)` interface.  It is suitable for waiting for changes to
>   files from shell scripts.  It can either exit once an event occurs, or
>   continually execute and output events as they occur.

Finding examples is left as an exercise...